# boost::asio simple identity stream

Tags: c++, boost, stream, asio

Is there a stream class provided by boost::asio for simple synchronous/asynchronous reading/writing to it?

eg.

```
simple_stream s;
std::size_t bytes_written = s.write_some("test");
std::size_t bytes_read = s.read_some();
```

I would like to create some mockup ports to replace my serial port for testing and such a stream would help connect components operating on Sync/Async-Read/Write streams. I couldn't find anything relevant from the documentation and I would like to also support coroutines in the asynchronous operations which seems to require using asio's detail::async_result_init. If possible I would prefer to avoid writing this if another solution is available.

Edit:

I have a serial communication between my pc and another device. 
These communicate with a specific protocol. The pc uses a PacketDispatcher object that listens to an AsyncReadStream (in my case the serial_port) and uses a parser to detect valid packages to dispatch using a given callback. I have another class that sends commands to an AsyncWriteStream (in my case the serial_port). Now I want to emulate the device in my pc and I want a simple AsyncStream to replace the serial port given to the above classes.

Comment: What is the specific use case and latency requirements? `asio::streambuf`?

Comment: @bobah some components require an AsyncReadStream to read from while others require an AsyncWriteStream to write to. Asio's serial_port is both an AsyncReadStream and an AsyncWriteStream so it is used to bridge those components together. I would like to have a simple identity AsyncStream to replace serial_port for testing.

Comment: A "deep mock" would be to use a loopback socket - either TCP or Unix domain, or a Unix pipe. Anything with a file descriptor that can be hooked into an epoll(). If you just want to mock the iostream part of it - boost::iostream has wrappers around a char array / std::vector.